# How to implement pagination in list view in android

Tags: android

How do I implement pagination in list view in android? I have to show 10 records per page. If the user clicks the next button I have to show another 10 records, and so on.
Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add the first 10 items into your adapter and show it. if your user clicks on next, change the data inside your adapter and call notifydatasetchanged(). this will reload the list with the new items.
but i think it is not a really good design to show only a few items instead of all possible items. personally it would drive me crazy.

Comment: @ZaZ Gmy can you please tell how maintain the state in arraylist while adding record and removing record depend upon the click i have to add next 10

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom adapter. populate `Listview` with `ArrayList` and then add ten items to `ArrrayList` and call `adapter.notfiyDataSetChange()`. when user click next button remove first ten items from `ArrrayList` and add next ten then again call `adapter.notfiyDataSetChange()`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do these steps:-

First you have to provide the button in the listView which is used by the user for loading next 10 records like this:-

```
//LoadMore Button
         Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
         btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

         //Adding Load More button to listview at bottom
         lview.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
```

and use the custom adopter:-

```
adapter = new myAdapter(this, record1, record2, stringArray);
         lview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now

```
/**
          * Listening to Load More button click event
          * */
         btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 // Starting a new async task
                 new loadMoreListView().execute();
             }
         }
```

And then use

```
    /**
             * Async Task that send a request to url
             * Gets new list view data
             * Appends to list view
             * */
            private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                       protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                                 (put your logic for load data)

                //get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
                        int currentPosition = lview.getFirstVisiblePosition();

    adapter = new myAdapter(NewsActivity.this, record1, record2, stringArray);
                      lview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Setting new scroll position
         lview.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

        }               
    });

    return (null);
}
```

Hope this will helps you...